# Grafting branches on rootstock

Tags: grafting

I have recently gotten into grafting. I just finished grafting my apple scions to my rootstocks. During that process I came up with a question. Typically you graft your scion to the trunk of the rootstock, somewhat low down on it. But if you planted the rootstock, let it develop branches, then grafted your desired scion(s) to the branches instead, would that work?

Comment: I seem to recall that it is possible to graft multiple types of scion to a single rootstock. That way you can have the wondrous spectacle of multiple types of apple on one tree. Even such glories as the tree having sequential flowering of different colors.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but it's reputed to be very difficult to maintain, as generally whatever the most vigorous scion is will tend to "take over" and corrective pruning to prevent that is an ongoing battle you'll have to fight every year.

So it's not commonly done, in practice.